# Mac OS X - How to delete automatic scripts or application actions?

Tags: macos, script, scheduled-tasks, crontab, launchd

I've a script installed that regularly executes on the full hour. A friend of mine installed it way back and I finally want to get rid of it. The problem: neither do I know the path to which it was installed nor the name of the file/process.

I've come across answers that direct to the /usr/bin, /usr/sbin or /usr/local/... folders. But facing the amount of files and not knowing what to look for - I am lost.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

After sorting through the launchd list via terminal (type "launchctl list" in terminal), the /.bash_history and the /System/Libarby/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic* plists - I realized it could be a schedule under crontab as well. [1][2]

In terminal enter: "crontab -e" to see the scheduled jobs. If your unfamiliar with the vim editor you can change to nano[3].

cheers

[1] https://blog.beezwax.net/2012/06/11/list-cron-entries-for-all-users-on-mac-os-x/

[2] ole (DOT) michelsen (DOT) dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html

[3] http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/nano-vs-vim-terminal-text-editors-compared/